# jQuery UI Sortable containment unable to detect placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

So I was working on this application where I want people to be able to drag items from one table data to the other table data, which must be contained within the parent table row.

But whenever I drag it around it seems to stick to the containment excluding the height of any placeholders.

Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/2wy8R/

Any idea of how I can make it select the parent of the parent? Of not, then, how can I make the placeholders count?

Greetings

```
.
```

Update: YouTube video of the problem http://youtu.be/PMXcQvJmRGw

Comment: can u create a js fiddle of this issue

Comment: @Arunu http://jsfiddle.net/2wy8R/ and I updated the first post

Comment: not sure what your problem is? what you have looks ok to me, can you explain a bit more

Comment: @Chimoo added a YouTube video and fixed my text

Comment: have a look through the api http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-over it looks like it's caching the height, so you may need to tell it to refresh its cache when you go over the list making it expand

Comment: ahhh, now I see what you are trying to do

Comment: another option could be to not use the normal containment and code your own version from inside the 'start' event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here you go. Overridden the default containment as it seems buggy with your scenario. Let me know if this is not a good idea but it seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/2wy8R/6/

```
$('#first, #second').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height() - 4);
        var p = $(ui.helper);
        var tr = p.closest("tr");
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
            var pOffset = p.offset();
            var trOffset = tr.offset();
            if (pOffset.left < trOffset.left) {
                p.css({left: trOffset.left});   
            }
            if (pOffset.left + p.width() > trOffset.left + tr.width()) {
                p.css({left: trOffset.left + tr.width() - p.width()});   
            }
            if (pOffset.top < trOffset.top) {
                p.css({top: trOffset.top});   
            }
            if (pOffset.top + p.height() > trOffset.top + tr.height()) {
                p.css({top: trOffset.top + tr.height() - p.height()});   
            }
        });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

just be careful with it though, as this keeps adding mousemove events to the document. you may want to unbind mousemove before binding it...

Comment: And, yes, thats the solution, thank you! It works just like I expected the containment to work :) Do you think I should report this on the jQuery UI bug website?

Comment: probably, I don't know enough about jquery UI to know if this is a bug or not but they will tell you there

Comment: I'm not questioning this answer, but, what is the difference in functionality between this fiddle and the one in the question?

Comment: look at his youtube video, the default containment doesn't let him get all the way to the bottom of the table row

Comment: Updated your code a little bit with a check whether there's an item being moved yes/no. http://jsfiddle.net/2wy8R/7/ Thanks again :)